# Is a triple-sworded style viable against one or dual wielding sword oppenents?

Tags: weapons, style, sword

I was wondering if using three swords with the third in your mouth would be effective against anyone else with a sword. I'd think so, because you could parry their attacks, and then slice them with the third blade by moving your neck.

Here's an example of triple sword wielding.

[image]

Comment: No.  No, it's not.

Comment: As fun as the One Piece Manga is, martial arts from it are not real.   Though, the rentjong dagger from Indonesia is designed to be held by the toes against the foot, and can be used with two daggers in the hands.  Nonetheless, it's better as a surprise weapon than "3 weapon style".

Comment: "Less is more."

Comment: What the ####?  I hope that's not you in that picture. What happens when I strike that sword and break all your teeth?

Comment: Please tell me you are wearing underwear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, please no. Just don't.

And no, it will not be effective. Even given that there are some people that can tow trains by ropes in their teeth, you cannot clench your jaw enough to be able to hold on to it if someone hits the blade. It will spin out, and if you are lucky, leave your teeth behind.

Second, despite what they show in cartoons, you are much more likely to hit the sword yourself, either on the way through for a strike or when drawing back. Add to that, you can't really generate enough force to cut deep enough to do the damage you want merely by twisting your neck around, unless you get lucky.

So in effect, you are risking a lot of damage and limiting your effective attack. Even your right hand sword (as shown in the picture) will be of limited effectiveness since you are only using one hand and missing the "push pull" action that gives your strikes the most force.

Answer (score 1):

I have at least three things to say.

1. I HIGHLY doubt the triple sword style would be effective in real life. And even if that wasn't the case, Zoro is darn near superhuman, which is probably why he is the ONLY one who mastered this style.
2. Is that YOU in the picture?
3. If this is you in the picture, I have to say you are both bold AND reckless. If this is what it looks like, you are not only risking your modesty by posting yourself butt naked, you are also risking your the health of your teeth and "other parts" by carrying THREE sharp, presumably heavy swords, knowing one wrong move could do a LOT of damage. The three sword style is impossible, but for this bravery, I commend you dude.

Answer (score 1):

No. Nope. Definitely not. No. No. Just.... No. If you're going to dual wield anything in your off-hand, use a buckler. Manga, anime, movies and video game tropes are worthless in actual combat. Every warrior culture wielding melee arms throughout history have always, without fail gravitated to pole-arms (re: spears) and shields. The republic Roman army did indeed use the Gladius (shortsword), however the Pilum (javelin) was still prevalent, and the Hasta (lance) would return to prominence later on. Swords are sidearms. Back up for when your pole-arm is lost. Best used with a shield or two handed in the case of longswords, zweihanders, montantes, no daichi, etc.

Answer (score -2):

HOW strong are your teeth you can hold a sword in your mouth to successfully use. Even worse, holding a sword with your mouth means bringing your head in close proximity to an opponent.
Here's the most basic thing about swords, ANY SWORD, no matter the culture. When they hit too many hard things, they stop being sharp. In movies, those photogenic edge-to-edge sword fights make swords appear indestructable, it's good drama.
[image]
IN Reality a fight with blade on blade action quickly turn any razor-sharp blades into nothing more than a glorified stick. After a few sword strikes, chips and damage will occur and ruin the blade.
[image]
That's why japanese sword smiths devote especially extra attention to sharpening blades. But if the sword cracks extend past the core, if the cracks are sufficiently deep the sword is ruined forever and typically has to be reworked or recycled.
Real sword fights focus on parrying, diverting or stopping blade strikes or with the non-sharp end being struck. Holding swordwith your mouth.......break your teeth...with a sword strike